# I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:missing org.springframework.util.MimeType

Tags: java, spring-mvc, classnotfoundexception, weblogic12c

I have a problem with NetBeans IDE. I am new to this IDE and now working on project, which uses Spring MVC + Hibernate, the server side is on Oracle Weblogic 12c.
Everything was fine, but today I get this error, while deploying the project: `Deployment failed. The message was: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.MimeType`
My pom.xml file:

```
 <properties>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
     <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
     </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: You have `spring-core` in the exclusions. MimeType is a part of core.

Comment: @StanislavL unfortunately correcting this doesn't help.

Comment: Try implicitly add spring-core dependency.

Comment: @StanislavL thank you, that resolved problem for me.

Comment: Then accept the answer as correct)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spring core exclusion should be removed.

```
  <exclusion>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
```

and the `spring-core` dependency should be added to the pom.

Comment: How did you find this solution just from reading the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.MimeType`

Comment: It's relatively easy. There is no class. It means class is not added to the classpath - the dependency is missing (or the class is somehow excluded). Then need to find what dependency is correct for the class - just google **maven dependency `<class here>`**. Done